# Transfer data with 'geometry' to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, geometry, elasticsearch

I would like to transfer my data which contains `'geometry'` to Elasticsearch but I don't know how to change my 'body'. `'geometry'` is the last column. What should I change?

Code:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
bulk = Bulk(es, index_name ='gis-test' , max_size = 5)


budynki = geopandas.read_file(r'/home/gis/budynkipolska/bdot10k_bubd_a.gpkg', rows=slice(0, 50),  encoding = "cp1250")
adresy = geopandas.read_file(r'/home/gis/adresypolska/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp', rows=slice(0, 50),  encoding = "cp1250")
budynki = pd.DataFrame(budynki)


def export_elastic(powiat,lokalnyid,wersjaid,status_bdot,nazwa,kategoria_bdot,funkcja_ogolna_budynku,funkcja_szczegolowa_budynku,liczba_kondygnacji,zabytek,skrot_karto,aktualnosc_geometrii,aktualnosc_atrybutow,kod_kst,geometry):
    body2 = {
        'classification': {
                'powiat': powiat,
                'lokalnyid': lokalnyid,
                'wersjaid': wersjaid,
                'status_bdot': status_bdot,
                'nazwa': nazwa,
                'kategoria_bdot': kategoria_bdot,
                'funkcja_ogolna_budynku': funkcja_ogolna_budynku,
                'funkcja_szczegolowa_budynku': funkcja_szczegolowa_budynku,
                'liczba_kondygnacji': liczba_kondygnacji,
                'zabytek': zabytek,
                'skrot_karto': skrot_karto,
                'aktualnosc_geometrii': aktualnosc_geometrii,
                'aktualnosc_atrybutow': aktualnosc_atrybutow,
                'kod_kst': kod_kst,
                'geometry': geometry, #<----- HERE
            }
        }
    return(body2)


for index, row in budynki.iterrows():
    print(row['geometry'])
    powiat = row['powiat']
    lokalnyid = row['lokalnyid']
    wersjaid = row['wersjaid']
    status_bdot = row['status_bdot']
    nazwa = row['nazwa']
    kategoria_bdot = row['kategoria_bdot']
    funkcja_ogolna_budynku = row['funkcja_ogolna_budynku']
    funkcja_szczegolowa_budynku = row['funkcja_szczegolowa_budynku']
    liczba_kondygnacji = row['liczba_kondygnacji']
    zabytek = row['zabytek']
    skrot_karto = row['skrot_karto']
    aktualnosc_geometrii = row['aktualnosc_geometrii']
    aktualnosc_atrybutow = row['aktualnosc_atrybutow']
    kod_kst = row['kod_kst']
    geometry = row['geometry']
    body2 = export_elastic(powiat,lokalnyid,wersjaid,status_bdot,nazwa,kategoria_bdot,funkcja_ogolna_budynku,funkcja_szczegolowa_budynku,liczba_kondygnacji,zabytek,skrot_karto,aktualnosc_geometrii,aktualnosc_atrybutow,kod_kst,geometry)
    res = es.index(index = 'gis-test', body = body2, doc_type = '_doc')
    bulk.append_body(body = body2, id_doc = index, method='update')
bulk.commit()
```

Screen:
[image]